# How to redirect user to random part of url and this url should match jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

I use servlets 3 and jsp and this is configuration question.

In servlet for url 'mydomain.com/builder/', I have to generate random ID and append it to my current url, like:

```
'mydomain.com/builder/randomID0'
```

Next, I want to redirect user to this url. So I need to match this new url to existent jsp page.

How to do this in servlet 3?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the current url as a `String` object via the `getRequestURI()` method of the `HTTPServletRequest` class, then generate the randomID String object and concatenate one another into a `newUrl` String.

Then use `sendRedirect(newUrl)` of the `HTTPServletResponse` class in order to let the user navigate to that new url.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to send user jsp file but rewrite url

Comment: Don'r redirect to another url but only rewrite url

Comment: In this case, you would need to use a sendRedirect in order to rewrite the url for the client, then make it process into a servlet and use the `forward()` method of `RequestDispatcher` class in order to send the client the wanted JSP file while still keeping the old url (if I understood what you want to do)

Comment: Can I change url in filter after httpservlet ?

Comment: What do you mean for filter? Is it the browser's address bar?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to redirect from `/pc-builder/` to `/pc-builder/<myId>` and don't harm SEO rank of `/pc-builder/` page.